# Можно ли с помощью ContentObserver узнать какая запись в БД была изменена?

Tags: android

Я использую `ContentObserver` в своём приложении. Когда БД, к которой я добавил указатель на `ContentObserver`, измениться, срабатывает метод `onChange()` ContentObserver-а, но он лишь даёт узнать, что БД была изменена. Можно ли как-то узнать какая именно строка была изменена без проверки целой БД?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только с API 16 можно получить `Uri` записи:

[public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html#onChange(boolean, android.net.Uri))

Comment: это очень плохо,ибо моё приложение должно работать на телефонах с min API 11 lvl

Comment: Я проверил URI, которое оно возвращает. Там лишь только Uri с путём к БД, но строка БД не указана

Comment: Чтобы был `Uri` записи надо при регистрации слушателя указывать `Uri` записи. В случае с БД контактов - есть `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI`... ну то есть по сути придется на каждую запись пихать по слушателю (вернее слушатель то будет один, но регистраций будет много)

Comment: А на производительность это влиять не будет? И ещё вопрос, можно ли всё-таки на API lvl 11 что-то подобное замутить или только API 16 и выше?

Comment: И ещё вопрос. Я не изменяю БД контактов но в логах периодически выскакивает сообщение,что БД была изменена,с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Не знаю...

Comment: Я разобрался почему срабатывает изменение БД, хотя изменение самого контакта не производилось, это связано с тем,что в той же БД хранятся совершённые вами звонки, т.е. она будет обновляться, когда вы позвоните или система что-нибудь сделает с этими записями звонков и т.п., поэтому метод onChange() будет реагировать и на такие изменения